# On a domain, how do you define new user properties

Tags: windows, dns, active-directory, ou

I'm not sure the official name of these user properties so I'll explain them:

In Active Directory Users and Computers, if you right-click a user, hit "properties", than look under the "general" tab you'll see

- First name
- initials
- last name
- description
- office
- etc..

Is it possible to add a custom property, let's say, "twitter username", to each user? And what's the name of these properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, what I was looking for was **extending the user schema**

a good tutorial to do this is [over here](http://www.petri.com/add_additional_attributes_to_user_objects.htm)